# Calendar tomá febrero como primer mes del año

Tags: java, date

Tengo una función que lo que debe hacer es lo siguiente:

Devolver una lista con todos los meses del año seleccionado sí el año es el actual, solo devolver los meses hasta la fecha actual.

Sin embargo por alguna extraña razón me devuelve la lista como si el primer mes del año fuera febrero y el ultimo diciembre. ¿Por qué ocurre estó?

```
    public List<String> getMeses() {
    String[] mesesSt = {"Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", " ;Septiembre",
        "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"};
    List<String> meses = new ArrayList();

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

    calendar.setTime(new Date());

    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);

    for (int i = 0; calendar.getTime().before(new Date()) && i < 12; i++) {
        System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
        meses.add(mesesSt[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)]);
    }
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());

    return meses;
}
```

Comment: Simplemente porque inicializas la fecha a enero antes del bucle, pero dentro del bucle le agregas un mes (`calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);`) antes de acumular los resultados en tu lista.  Por lo que la lista comienza con febrero.

Comment: (calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1) es para sumar, no para asignar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error era que primero estaba sumando los meses y después los agregaba en la lista, lo correcto es así:

```
public List<String> getMeses() {
String[] mesesSt = {"Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", " ;Septiembre",
    "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"};
List<String> meses = new ArrayList();

Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

calendar.setTime(new Date());

calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);

for (int i = 0; calendar.getTime().before(new Date()) && i < 12; i++)     {
    System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));

    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
    meses.add(mesesSt[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)]);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
}
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());

return meses;
}
```

Comment: Aunque me alegra que tu problema está resuelto, el código me parece bien confuso para lo que estás tratando de hacer.¿Por qué no usas directamente el array `mesesSt`? No entiendo lo que el método intenta lograr aparte de devolver los 12 meses en orden, que ya los tienes en la variable `mesesSt`.

Comment: La cosa es que si estamos por ejemplo, en el mes de febrero de este año, entonces solo quiero que me devuelva enero y febrero, pero sí el año previamente seleccionado es uno anterior entonces debe mostrar todos los meses